# Error while executing hello world in Concourse

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

concourse hello world is not getting executed.
I followed hello world from the below url
https://concoursetutorial.com/basics/task-hello-world/

git clone https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial.git
cd concourse-tutorial/tutorials/basic/task-hello-world
fly -t tutorial execute -c task_hello_world.yml

Below are the Errors i am getting.. Can anyone point me to the right direction, some permission denied errors are coming for config.json.

```
Mar  7 04:49:23 bishwajitsamanta16891c concourse_worker[7683]: {"timestamp":"1551934163.558898449","source":"guardian","message":"guardian.api.garden-server.run.failed","log_level":2,"data":{"error":"runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"chdir to cwd (\\\"/root\\\") set in config.json failed: permission denied\"\n","handle":"9c8d67ca-0994-482c-5ef4-89b8993afb83","session":"3.1.13"}}
Mar  7 04:49:23 bishwajitsamanta16891c concourse_web[7673]: {"timestamp":"1551934163.559687376","source":"atc","message":"atc.create-build.image.failed-to-get-latest-image-version","log_level":2,"data":{"container":"bc21e0c6-ad3a-4650-5539-d7813e3f33ac","error":"Backend error: Exit status: 500, message: {\"Type\":\"\",\"Message\":\"runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \\\"chdir to cwd (\\\\\\\"/root\\\\\\\") set in config.json failed: permission denied\\\"\\n\",\"Handle\":\"\",\"ProcessID\":\"\",\"Binary\":\"\"}\n","session":"131.2"}}



root@bishwajitsamanta16891c:~# fly -t my-ci ws
name                                    containers  platform  tags  team  state    version
bishwajitsamanta16891c.mylabserver.com  0           linux     none  none  running  2.0


cloud_user@bishwajitsamanta16891c:~/concourse-tutorial/tutorials/basic/task-hello-world$ sudo fly -t my-ci execute -c task_hello_world.yml
executing build 12 at http://172.31.20.27:8080/builds/12
initializing
Backend error: Exit status: 500, message: {"Type":"","Message":"runc exec: exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused \"chdir to cwd (\\\"/root\\\") set in config.json failed: permission denied\"\n","Handle":"","ProcessID":"","Binary":""}

errored


task_hello_world.yml
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: ubuntu}

run:
  path: echo
  args: [hello world]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys issue is resolved, i just uninstalled Docker.